# Wait cursor till UI is ready. How to?

Tags: wpf

I have a ListView with several hundred complex element. When the collection that is bound to the ListView has been filled with data it takes several seconds till the UI becomes responsive. My wait cursor turn back to regular once the collection is filled, but I would like it to stay in wait till the UI is responsive. I'm not sure what's going on in the background but I guess the WPF elements are initialized. Is there an event I can wait for till WPF is done with its updating?

(It's fine for the user to wait as long as a wait cursor it shown.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class in your project call it UIServices here is the code

```
/// <summary>
///   Contains helper methods for UI, so far just one for showing a waitcursor
/// </summary>
public static class UIServices
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   A value indicating whether the UI is currently busy
    /// </summary>
    private static bool IsBusy;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the busystate as busy.
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetBusyState()
    {
        SetBusyState(true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the busystate to busy or not busy.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="busy">if set to <c>true</c> the application is now busy.</param>
    private static void SetBusyState(bool busy)
    {
        if (busy != IsBusy)
        {
            IsBusy = busy;
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = busy ? Cursors.Wait : null;

            if (IsBusy)
            {
                new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, dispatcherTimer_Tick, System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Tick event of the dispatcherTimer control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private static void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dispatcherTimer = sender as DispatcherTimer;
        if (dispatcherTimer != null)
        {
            SetBusyState(false);
            dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your viewmodel or code behind as follows:

```
 UIServices.SetBusyState();
```

This will give users the wait cursor till your application is busy

Comment: What's the trick? Is it that TimeSpan(0) means: Come back as soon as you can which is equivalent to: As soon as the event queue is empty?